# Android App crashes when run from phone but works fine in emulator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Recently my android app crash when it tested on real device. but it works fine while tested on emulator. My app has fragment that implement RecyclerView and when the item in RecyclerView clicked it will start new Detail activity, and it crash when back press button clicked. I've role back to the previous commit that works on device but it still crashing.
this the Error Log :

```
07-10 14:07:15.146 12250-12250/com.luckyendey.polymarkapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.luckyendey.polymarkapp, PID: 12250
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.luckyendey.polymarkapp/com.luckyendey.polymarkapp.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.luckyendey.polymarkapp.bonsementara.BonSementaraHeaderTabOpenFragment$LayoutManagerType.ordinal()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.luckyendey.polymarkapp.bonsementara.BonSementaraHeaderTabOpenFragment$LayoutManagerType.ordinal()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.luckyendey.polymarkapp.bonsementara.BonSementaraHeaderTabOpenFragment.setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(BonSementaraHeaderTabOpenFragment.java:98)
                                                                            at com.luckyendey.polymarkapp.bonsementara.BonSementaraHeaderTabOpenFragment.onCreateView(BonSementaraHeaderTabOpenFragment.java:60)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2900)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2207)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1326)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2900)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

This is My code :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_purchase_request_open, container, false);

    access_token = GlobalMethod.getPref("access_token",getContext());

    presenter = new PurchaseRequestHeaderOpenPresenter(this);
    presenter.getListDataPurchaseRequest(access_token,"");
    presenter.getRequestType(access_token);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_purchase_request_open);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore saved layout manager type.
        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER); // this is return null that causing the error
    }

    setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(mCurrentLayoutManagerType);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_purchase_request_open);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,R.color.colorAccent,R.color.colorPrimary);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            presenter.getListDataPurchaseRequest(access_token,"");
        }
    });

    return  view;
}
```

On emulator onCreateView not trigger when back press clicked on detail activity, but in device it call again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been solved this problem by turning off **Don't keep activities** under **Developer Options**. I forgot that I was enabled it and now my app works great.